# SqlDataAdapter object in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-express

I am running `Visual Studio 2010` and `SQL Server 2008 Express` editions. I have created a database in SQL called **Hangman.mdf**. Then in `Visual Studio` I drag the `SqlDataAdapter` object to my form and it brings up the wizard, in the wizard under data source I select the `Microsoft SQL Server Database File` (SqlClient) and then browse to my **Hangman.mdf** file. When I click on test connection it throws out this error:

```
Unable to open physical file "C:\XXX\Hangman.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)" An attempt to attach an auto named database for file C:\XXX\Hangman.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

I am running `Windows 8`, I have opened up `Visual Studio` and `SQL Server` as `Administrator`.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: can you connect to the database from SQL Server Management studio ? What is your complete connection string ?

Comment: why don't you use `Microsoft SQL Server` instead, in wizard - data source?

Comment: make sure your sqlserver is up to date, unless it is

SQL Server 2008 Express SP3 and above.
SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP1 and above.
SQL Server 2012 Express.

it's not supported